# Portable load/include of define-syntax in R5RS Scheme?

Tags: racket, r5rs, gambit

I'm trying to write something that works in both DrRacket/plt-r5rs and Gambit/gsi.

The problem I'm having is that `(load "foo.scm")` in Gambit does not load `define-syntax`-blocks. Using `(include "foo.scm")` in Gambit works, but of course results in a syntax error in DrRacket.

Is there any way to solve this so that I can write portable R5RS code?

Things I've tried:

- Redefining `(include "foo.scm")` to `(load "foo.scm")` and vice versa. Problem: Illegal to redefine macros in Gambit.
- Wrapping said redefinitions in an `(if gambit ...)`. Problem: Illegal to put define inside if(unless inside another define).
- Passing string with filename to an include in the library file instead. Problem: Includes in Gambit seem to happen before interpretation starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to write a module that's compatible with both Gambit and Racket.

There are indeed ways you can test for a specific implementation and define things conditionally. There are, in fact, two systems for doing this: [SRFI 0](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-0/srfi-0.html) and [SRFI 7](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-7/srfi-7.html). [Most implementations support one or the other. Not very many support both.](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-implementers.html)

Gambit supports SRFI 0. Racket supports SRFI 7.

Comment: To Erik: you picked this as the best answer...so what did you do?

Comment: I pretty much gave up on making the code I was working on portable between Gambit and Racket, as it was not really a requirement for that particular project, but just something that would be nice. Especially when I figured out how to get what I wanted from Gambit in Racket(the answer to the question "is this currently running in a terminal?").

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps: In Racket you can use include in r5rs files:

```
#lang r5rs
(#%require (only racket include))
(include "foo.scm")
```

If you define `#%require` to do nothing in Gambit, then you can use the same source file in both implementations.

Comment: Since part of the problem I'm having is that I can't redefine something for only one of them I can't see how I can use this. Am I missing something?

Comment: When you invoke gsi you can give it a list of files. The first can contain Gambit specific definitions.

Comment: As far as I remember racket has the same functionality so then I could just do `(define include load)` in that file. Don't like making assumptions on how the code is run, but I guess it's the closest I'll get.